# How to convert iso-8601 timestamp to MySQL DATETIME

Tags: mysql, facebook, datetime, timestamp

I've searched for this conversion and have found the opposite.

I'm pulling facebook page feeds using the graph api and the date format it gives is iso-8601.

I need to convert that to mysql timestamp to add it to my database. Most search results provide mysql to iso.

Can I get a direct conversion or do I have to convert to unix then mysql or something like that.

Comment: Also, make your life simple by specifying in graph api calls that you want to return unix time http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ #dates

Answer (score 4):

Use the mysql function `STR_TO_DATE(str,format)` in your update statement:

```
 UPDATE [table] SET [field] = STR_TO_DATE([your input date], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s+0000');
```

The `STR_TO_DATE` function takes 2 parameters 1)your date string and 2)the format for the output which can be formatted in the same way as `mysql DATE_FORMAT()` See: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: The format I needed to parse was described in the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 as this sample: 2017-09-20T18:12:02+00:00

To parse this one, I added a colon to the timezone mask: '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s+00:00'

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE( '2012-06-25T20:05:13+0000', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s+0000' )
```

This works for dates with the timezone set to +0000 (what is what FB Graph API normally returns).

I you need to convert datetimes *with* a timezone other than +0000, you could split that datestring first, perform `STR_TO_DATE` on the first part, and use `DATE_ADD` to add the offset specified in the second part.

Comment: This is a select statement right. Using php I need to format the iso-8601 date format to be saved in a mysql date timestamp

Comment: _“This is a select statement right.”_ – nothing get’s past you, eagleeye … _“Using php I need to format the iso-8601 date format to be saved in a mysql date timestamp”_ – you can put that function _into_ your SQL query, and just put the datestring into it dynamically.

Comment: @Cbroe is suggesting you use the STR_TO_DATE function in your INSERT query, and allow MySQL to convert the ISO time string to its internal format. Note that you probably want to do this MySQL statement immediately before you insert one of these +0000 dates so the timezone offset is correct for these UTC times fed you by FB. `SET time_zone='+00:00'`